# SSRS Error "The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: Months" caused by a data series?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been building a graph in SSRS for a client and I keep running into this error "The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: Months" when I try to add a particular series to the graph:

[image]

Now what's interesting here is that it's reacting to the data, and here's a screenshot of what my dataset looks like:

[image]

The problem child is the "Trailing_12_Month_Sum" column. For whatever reason it just doesn't like those numbers. Point in case, if I edit the proc that returns them to simply return 0 (or even a constant like 80,000!), then the graph works fine. Here's what happens when I monkey with the proc:

[image]

And the graph is now happy (You can see the flat 80K line below):

[image]

I also tried higher numbers like 10 mil and that rendered fine as well. The only other data point I have on this is the error I pulled from the SSRS error logs, which isn't really that helpful since it doesn't tell you where the error came from in relation to the chart.

> library!WindowsService_44!2268!10/06/2014-18:18:47:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
>   reportrendering!ReportServer_0-90!2244!10/06/2014-18:24:19:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: Not a legal OleAut date. ---> System.ArgumentException: Not a legal OleAut date.
>      at System.DateTime.DoubleDateToTicks(Double value)
>      at System.DateTime.FromOADate(Double d)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.AxisScale.CalcInterval(Double min, Double max, Boolean date, DateTimeIntervalType& type, ChartValueTypes valuesType)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.Grid.Paint(ChartGraphics graph)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.Axis.PaintGrids(ChartGraphics graph, Boolean selectionMode, Int32 x, Int32 y, Object& obj)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.Axis.PaintGrids(ChartGraphics graph)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.ChartArea.Paint(ChartGraphics graph)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly, RenderingType renderingType, XmlTextWriter svgTextWriter, Stream flashStream, String documentTitle, Boolean resizable, Boolean preserveAspectRatio)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.ChartImage.GetImage(Single resolution)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.Chart.Save(Stream imageStream, ChartImageFormat format)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ChartMapper.GetImage(ImageType imageType)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;

I don't have any idea why in the world simply added that series (as you saw there were several others working just fine) is causing this error. It's just a column of ints, why the data error is occurring I have no idea.

I'm using VS2012 for report development and we're on ssrs 2012.

If any SSRS gurus out there can help me out I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the stored procedure's calculation of the preceding 12 months is throwing the error. Hopefully you are using something like `DateAdd(mm, -12, SomeDate)` rather than building the previous 12 month date from a string which may yield an invalid date.

Comment: The first pic of the dataset is of the unmodified proc results returning the data correctly using the same params as in the report. It doesn't throw an error in sql server so I'm 99% sure that the error isn't coming from the proc. Also, I have a Trailing Avg (off to the right of my pics, you can't see it) that is calc'ed identically to the sum column (but Avg of course) and it's fine, no problems in any scenario. Also note the err log, error's coming from a rendering func trying to convert a double to ticks, I have no idea why it would try and do that.

Comment: Is it trying to convert the number you return from your sp into an unrepresentable date? Something higher than 31 December 9999? Try setting your return value to 999999999 (i.e. higher than maxdate) and see if it blows up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try casting column to maximum decimal, it helped in my case...

CAST(Trailing_12_Month_Sum AS DECIMAL(38,0)) as Trailing_12_Month_Sum

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your axis settings. You need to make sure that the vertical and horizontal axis both have the right "interval type" settings.

1. click on your chart
2. select the axis
3. right click, properties
4. in the "major tick marks" and "minor tick marks" page you'll have the interval settings at the bottom under "set custom interval"
   In the "interval type" field choose something other than default.